# How to interpret "как раз" in this context?

Tags: значения

> Дует попутный ветер, и **как раз** прилив, а ...
>
> == The wind is kicking up and the tide is **exactly** (**...**), but ...

If I go on the definition shown on [Wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7), some word or phrase to describe the part inside (...) seems to be lacking in this Russian sentence. In English, a phrase such as "how we want it to be" is expected to follow the adverb "exactly"; after all, "exactly" cannot stand alone and you cannot say "the tide is exactly".

> == The wind is kicking up and the tide is **exactly** (**how we want it to be**), but ...

I suppose the adverbial phrase "как раз"  only has the meaning of "exactly" and the meaning doesn't extend to "exactly how we want it to be".

Does this Russian sentence have some (implied) missing word(s), or should I interpret the phrase "как раз" differently?

Comment: I would say the best match would be "fortunately" or "incidentally". Also, "by the way" can be used.

Comment: @Alexander Hi. I don't suppose you can say "прилив дует" unlike "ветер дует", can you? So is some verb omitted around "прилив"? Or is the adjective "попутный" implied before "прилив"?

Comment: "There is a tailwind, and, incidentally, it's a high tide"

Comment: And there's just the tide.

Comment: It is used to signify a lucky (although not too unusual) coincidence. Could be translated as "luckily", "fortunately", etc. Although, depending on the context, it sometimes may mean the opposite - e. g. unlucky (although still not too unusual) coincidence - then "unluckily", "unfortunately", etc.

Comment: The wind is kicking up and there's the tide TO BOOT.

Comment: TO BOOT is the best phrase for this context and it effectively renders the fact that a situation is serendipitously so. Tatiana's comment (with a little editing) is actually the best answer: The wind is kicking up and it's high tide to boot.

Answer (score 2):

In this context **как раз** points to a *lucky coincidence* ('**and** /*luckily*/, **it's high tide *at that***'): the addition of the second condition (high tide) to the first one (favourable wind), both being necessary for a sailing vessel to get closer to the shore.

Answer (score 2):

The are two ways to interpret **как раз** in this context to express that a condition or situation is viewed as an "added bonus," as it were:

1. **to boot** can be added to the end of the statement: ...and it's high tide *to boot*.
2. **as luck would have it** can be added before the statement: ...and, *as luck would have it*, it was high tide.

Note that both these statements can also point to an unfortunate eventuality, which can easily be sussed from the context or the tone of the speaker:

Some days it doesn't pay to get out of bed. This morning I woke up to an ant infestation in my bathroom, an eviction notice from my landlord and my cat died **to boot**.

It just wasn't our day; we robbed the store, got all the money, made a clean getaway, then, **as luck would have it**, a policeman pulled us over for having a brake light out.